# Deserialize a JSON that has a key variable jackson map ObjectMapper

Tags: android, jackson, mapper

JSON:

```
  {
    "id": "1704",
    "title": "Choice of Drink",
    "multiselect": 0,
    "maximum_selection": 1,
    "ac_items": 1,
    "Choice of Drink": [{
        "id": "8151",
        "name": "Lemon Ice Tea",
        "price": 0,
        "orig_price": 0
    }, {
        "id": "8152",
        "name": "Fresh Lime",
        "price": 0,
        "orig_price": 0
    }]
}
```

The problem is that the key "Choice of Drink" is a variable.How can I put this in a @JsonProperty, when I don't have the name?

Comment: Is there a fixed list of Strings values that the variable might take? Choice of Drink is one of them.

Comment: Have Jackson parse the dynamic key into a `Map<String, List<DrinkItem>>`.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari No , it isn't fixed

Comment: in the sample, "Choice of Drink" is the value. do you mean that the key "title" changes?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Yes, it changes . In the sample JSON, i have added only one JSONArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson's `@JsonAnySetter` annotation to direct all variable keys to one method and there you can assign/handle them as you wish:

```
public class Bar
{
    // known/fixed properties
    public String id;
    public String title;
    public int multiselect;
    public int maximum_selection;
    public int ac_items;

    // unknown/variable properties will go here
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setDrinks(String key, Object value)
    {
        System.out.println("variable key = '" + key + "'");
        System.out.println("value is of type = " + value.getClass());
        System.out.println("value toString = '" + value.toString() + "'");
    }
}
```

in the case of the sample input, the output is:

```
variable key = 'Choice of Drink'
value is of type = class java.util.ArrayList
value toString = '[{id=8151, name=Lemon Ice Tea, price=0, orig_price=0}, {id=8152, name=Fresh Lime, price=0, orig_price=0}]'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String,Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String,Map<String, String>> map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, mapType);
```

Comment: Please use Jackson.